# serving index.php file but location is different for different users

Tags: php, .htaccess

i m trying to figure out how to do this
i know in php if we have some folder and inside that if we have index.php then calling that folder location from url will serve index.php file
but problem is my path changes
for example

```
  xxyz.com/edit/2343
     xxyz.com/edit/2347
   xxyz.com/edit/2342
```

i cant serve with edit.php?2343 etc i have to serve like that only
how can i direct php to serve inde.php file when we call  xxyz.com/edit/2347
these url scheme
i guess with htaccess we can do this

Comment: Are you asking how to use rewrite rules or what is the question? You shouldn't have numerous `index.php` files if that is what you currently are doing.

Comment: how to serve these request without crating multiple index.php file for all those nbers , i guess yes htacess rule wil solve

Comment: `edit/(\d+)` rewrite to `index.php?page=edit&id=$1` then read GET values of `page` and `id`. That's 1 way. There are many ways to do this. Research mod-rewrite. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained